# R: Remove rows based on columns containing ? in the string

Tags: r

| MarkerName | Allele1 | Allele2 | Weight | Zscore | P-value | Direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:1167075 | a | g | 218.00 | 2.446 | 0.01446 | ?+ |
| 7:77652992 | t | c | 218.00 | 2.076 | 0.03789 | ?- |
| X:24811075 | a | g | 315.00 | 2.463 | 0.01378 | +? |
| 4:15645706 | t | c | 315.00 | 2.582 | 0.009817 | -? |
| 5:13478320 | g | a | 315.00 | 2.872 | 0.00222 | ++ |

I am trying to subset a data frame with this format to remove all rows that contain a ?. The issue that I am running into is that the +/- signs are being recognized as operator symbols and R is giving me the following error:

Error: invalid regular expression '?+', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'

My goal is to have a data frame that looks like this:

| MarkerName | Allele1 | Allele2 | Weight | Zscore | P-value | Direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5:13478320 | g | a | 315.00 | 2.872 | 0.002 | ++ |

Comment: `?` is a reserved character in regex, meaning the previous character/group is optional (0 or 1). You can escape it `"\\?"` or use `fixed=TRUE`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 is a good reference for things like that.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(Direction,'\\?', negate = T))
```

Example:

```
d = tibble(a = 1:3, b = c('+?', '?+', '++'))

      a b    
  <int> <chr>
1     1 +?   
2     2 ?+   
3     3 ++ 


d %>% filter(str_detect(b,'\\?', negate = T))


      a b    
  <int> <chr>
1     3 ++
```